# What's a good tag for ocean oriented GIS?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've seen several questions mentioning [seabed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=seabed).

And others mentioning [seafloor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=seafloor).

And more about [ocean bathymetry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=ocean%20bathymetry&submit=search).

Is there some tag that could tie all these together?

Update

I just went in and successfully added a tag for `seabed`.

But when I try to add `seafloor` as a synonym for `seabed`, I get this:
[image]

Is there some way around this?

Comment: We could keep them all by making them synonyms.

Comment: Suggestion - Oceanography as a group tag?

Comment: Good idea, mapperz, but it strikes me that "oceanography" is a lot broader than the mapping of the sea floor: that, more properly, is "bathymetry," pure and simple.  It could be appropriate to have separate [tag:oceanography] and [tag:bathymetry] tags.

Comment: In jest, how about a [boat-programming](http://web.archive.org/web/20100426125115/http://www.mattmcdole.com/boat/) tag?

Comment: 'cartography' tag is broad subject but we still have 124 questions tagged with it - suggest we 'keep them all by making them synonyms'.... see http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/760/carto-tag-should-be-merged-into-cartography

Comment: How about "offshore"?  It is more generic and inclusive than the other options.

Comment: @MatthewSnape  +1 That would make sense for users in the oil industry.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest "Marine".
This is consistent with the Arc Marine data model that is used for coastal, seas, and oceans (including sea beds).
http://dusk.geo.orst.edu/djl/arcgis/
(And despite the name, Arc Marine is not really Esri specific.)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I never would have thought to search on marine for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly one question so far has the [seabed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seabed) tag and nobody has a 5 score for it.  You perhaps intended to suggest synonyms for [bathymetry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bathymetry).  The interface is confusing, because it does not make it clear which of the two tag names will be replaced by the other.  To help you out, I have just made [seabed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seabed) and [seafloor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seafloor) synonyms for [bathymetry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bathymetry).

Comment: Thanks.  Seems strange that anyone can create a new tag, but can't create a synonym for the tag at the same time.

Comment: +1 Bathymetry is probably the most appropriate parent-tag for all of these, anyway.